# Convergence (or Divergence) of [(-1)^(n-1)*e^(1/n)]/n

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

so I'm trying to find out whether the following sum converges ot not

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{1/n}}{n}$$

I tried to prove it via the Liebnitz criterion, and got:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{1/n}}{n}=0$$

but now when i have to show that

$$ |a_{n+1}|<|a_n| $$

that is:
 $$     \frac{e^{1/(n+1)}}{n+1}<\frac{e^{1/n}}{n}    $$

but i only get to the point:

$$ \frac{|n|}{|n+1|}<e^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}  $$ or $$ ln(\frac{n}{n+1})<\frac{1}{n(n+1)} $$

does anyone know how to prove or disprove one of these inequalities, or an alternative way of testing the convergence (or divergence) of this series?

Comment: What about $\dfrac{n}{n+1}<1<e^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$? Btw, are you sure the sum is $1$?

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this sum can be represented in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: If you know that the sum is $1$, then the series converges.

Comment: sorry about the $$\Sigma=1$$, it was a lapsus

Answer (score 4):

Write it as $\sum_{n \geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{(e^{1/n} - 1)}{n} + \sum_{n \geq 1}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$.

$\dfrac{e^{1/n}-1}{n}$ is $\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$ so the first term converges absolutely, and the second term is known to converge.

Comment: this is nice, allows you to use the asymptotic estimate on the exponential nicely. +1

Comment: sorry if this is stupid, but what is $$ O(1/n^2) $$ ?

Comment: If $c_n  = (e^{1/n} - 1)/n$ then it means $|c_n| \leq K/n^2$ for some positive $K$. And so $\sum_{n \ge 1} |c_n|$ converges by the comparison test. You can see this is true because $n^2 c_n$  tends to a limit and so must be bounded.